# How do i push to github without letting the changes show on commits

Tags: git, github

I am moving from gitlab to github. I have sensitive data that contains my API keys that was originally committed and pushed. I want to individually push each commit to Github so prospective employers can see the message of each commit but i want to exclude my API keys commit message from being visible to people.
It's currently showing in older commits. How do i delete those commits?

Comment: You'll need to use something like `git filter-branch` to rewrite your history to not include the problematic commits (the easiest way is probably to just cut off the history after the latest commit containing the offending data, but more involved methods could be possible). Note that any re-write of history (which **will** be necessary) leads to the new git repository to not be compatible with the old (i.e. they'll be effectively different histories with no common root).

Comment: Ok but then rewriting history and force pushing a Git repository can lead to loss of data correct? also there are very old commits I'd like to keep

Comment: Yes, force pushing *can* lead to loss of data (some of which is actually intentional in this case, isn't it?). And yes, you can probably do some `filter-branch` trickery to ensure *only* the relevant files are purged from your history, but I don't know enough git to know what exactly that is.

Comment: same here i just started using it

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by running:

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~[N]
```

`[N]` is a placeholder for the parent of the last commit i was trying to remove, which is `HEAD~2^` or `HEAD~3`.

In my case I was trying to edit the last three commits so running
`$ git rebase -i HEAD~3` opened the editor then I was able to drop the conflicting commit from there.

Then I ran 
`$ git rebase --continue` and `$ git push --force`
and everything was fixed

Answer (score -1):

Externalize secrets and keys and possibly use solution like vault